# PHP Array in wrong format

Tags: php, arrays, json, while-loop, getjson

I have a query which I want the results inserted in an array so after all I'll encode it into a JSON, but my problem is that I want the data to be set like this:

> array[0] = project1, project2, project3;
>   array[1] = item1, item2, item3;

and I'm having this:

> array[0] = project1;
>   array[1] = project2;
>   array[2] = project3;

and so on..

this is what I've done so far:

```
$info = array();

    $items = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `vision`.`projects` WHERE  proj_area = 'area_1'");

        if (mysql_num_rows($items) != 0) { 
            while($proj = mysql_fetch_array($items)) {      

            $proj_name = $proj['proj_name'];
            $proj_beg = $proj['proj_beg'];
            $proj_end = $proj['proj_end'];

            array_push($info, $proj_name, $proj_beg, $proj_end );
        } 
    }

    echo json_encode($info);
```

my query result gave me these result:

> ["nome", "0000-00-00", "0000-00-00", "Projeto 2", "2016-12-12", "2020-07-30", "Projeto", "2017-02-03", "2018-03-10"]

and this is my $.getJSON code:

```
$.getJSON("includes/get_area.php",function(data){

                    console.log(data);
                    })
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: would you please update your question with your query result's array what you got in that array?

Comment: @BunkerBoy I've got the answer now, but i'll post the query result in case someone might find another way to solve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one; this will add a list in each one of the three array indexes.

```
$info = array();

$items = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `vision`.`projects` WHERE  proj_area = 'area_1'");
if (mysql_num_rows($items) != 0) {
    while($proj = mysql_fetch_array($items)) {
        $info[0][] = $proj['proj_name'];
        $info[1][] = $proj['proj_beg'];
        $info[2][] = $proj['proj_end'];
    }
}

echo json_encode($info);
```